# Mounting a SharePoint site in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, mount, gnome, webdav

I am trying to mount a SharePoint drive in Ubuntu 14.04, and utterly failing. It's an external site which uses a username that includes an @, and obviously a password.

First, I have tried to use [Nautilus from Gnome as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233242/how-do-i-establish-a-webdav-connection-in-gnome-3). With or without the username, it fails with 403 FORBIDDEN.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/851483/mount-sharepoint-online-office-365-in-linux) suggested Konqueror.
This one gets stuck
[image: Konqueror screen]
This is probably due to the fact that the rest of the system is Gnome, but still.

I have also tried to mount, using davfs2, the external drive. It requests the username, but then when the password is issued, again the same error, 403 FORBIDDEN.

Finally, I have used cadaver, as suggested elsewhere. Before even asking the password, it returns 403 FORBIDDEN.

Is it simply impossible to use 12.04 (and version of Gnome) for that? Should I uses something else entirely?